# What is the best way to align the two circleavatars?

Tags: user-interface, flutter, stack, widget

I am designing a screen like this in a Stack in Flutter.

The problem is I am taking the variables like viewport height and width into account while implementing in flutter and then when I build it, it is not displayed properly.

What I want:
[image]

And what I get:

[image]

**Any help?**

UPDATE:
This is the code for the Card I want the UI of.

```
class GameCard extends StatelessWidget {

final bool isNew = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        Card(
          clipBehavior: Clip.antiAliasWithSaveLayer,
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: <Widget>[
              CachedNetworkImage(
                imageUrl: CommonUrls.beginnersContestDefaultImage,
                fit: BoxFit.fill,
                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 7,
              ),
              Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text('Game Name', style: CommonTextStyles.getSubTitleTextStyleDark(context).copyWith(
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold
                    ),),
                    Text('4543', style: CommonTextStyles.getTitleTextStyleGray(context).copyWith(
                      fontSize: 12,
                      color: Colors.grey
                    ),),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
    isNew? Positioned(
      right: 4,
      top: 4,
      child: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 8.0, right: 18.0, left: 18.0, bottom: 8.0),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.white,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(topRight: Radius.circular(5.0), bottomLeft: Radius.circular(5.0),)
        ),
        child: Text('NEW', style: CommonTextStyles.getTitleTextStyleLight(context).copyWith(
          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
          fontSize: 14,
        ),),
      ),
    )
    : Container(),
    isNew? Positioned(
      right: 0,
      child: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 8.0, right: 18.0, left: 18.0, bottom: 8.0),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.red,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(topRight: Radius.circular(5.0), bottomLeft: Radius.circular(5.0),)
        ),
        child: Text('NEW', style: CommonTextStyles.getTitleTextStyleLight(context).copyWith(
          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
          fontSize: 14,
        ),),
      ),
    )
     : Container(),

    Positioned(
      bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 13,
      left: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width/7.5,
      child: Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 8.0, right: 8.0),
            child: CircleAvatar(
              backgroundColor: getColor(0xff8951d9),
              radius: 13,
                ),
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 8.0, right: 8.0),
            child: CircleAvatar(
              backgroundColor: getColor(0xff3e51b5),
              radius: 13,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
   ],
  );
 }
}
```

Comment: post your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Dhruvam, Not sure how you are calling your GameCard but there are quite a few things unrelated to avatar circle which could be affecting the alignment,

- Make sure you're calling GameCard inside GridView
- Calculate the number of cards based on the screen size
- Enclose CachedNeworkImage with Expanded to properly fill your card
- Set game title/number container height so that you can bottom-position your avatar accordingly
- Finally, left-position your avatar depending on the number of cards in a row

Example below based on your code should give you an idea. You might wanna play around with left-position a bit to support different screen sizes.

```
class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    double cardWidth = 150.0;
    int countRow = width ~/ cardWidth;// Calculate no. of cards in a row
    return MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
            body: SafeArea(
                child: GridView.count(
      primary: false,
      padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
      crossAxisSpacing: 10,
      mainAxisSpacing: 10,
      crossAxisCount: countRow,
      children: <Widget>[
        getGameCard(
            context,
            'https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcScDI-oN5NuYMe-Jxnou1U8ZyzBP_6dXTxx_DdB7Gcu_y9ksP-0aQ&s',
            true,
            countRow),
        getGameCard(
            context,
            'https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcScDI-oN5NuYMe-Jxnou1U8ZyzBP_6dXTxx_DdB7Gcu_y9ksP-0aQ&s',
            false,
            countRow),
        getGameCard(
            context,
            'https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcScDI-oN5NuYMe-Jxnou1U8ZyzBP_6dXTxx_DdB7Gcu_y9ksP-0aQ&s',
            false,
            countRow),
        getGameCard(
            context,
            'https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcScDI-oN5NuYMe-Jxnou1U8ZyzBP_6dXTxx_DdB7Gcu_y9ksP-0aQ&s',
            false,
            countRow),
        getGameCard(
            context,
            'https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcScDI-oN5NuYMe-Jxnou1U8ZyzBP_6dXTxx_DdB7Gcu_y9ksP-0aQ&s',
            false,
            countRow),
        getGameCard(
            context,
            'https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcScDI-oN5NuYMe-Jxnou1U8ZyzBP_6dXTxx_DdB7Gcu_y9ksP-0aQ&s',
            false,
            countRow),
      ],
    ))));
  }

  getGameCard(BuildContext context, String url, bool isNew, int rowCount) {
    return Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        Card(
              clipBehavior: Clip.antiAliasWithSaveLayer,
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Expanded(
                      child: CachedNetworkImage(
                    imageUrl: url,
                    fit: BoxFit.fill,
                  )),
                  Container(
                    height: 55.0,
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                    child: Column(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Text(
                          'Game Name',
                          style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                        ),
                        Text(
                          '4543',
                          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12, color: Colors.grey),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
        Positioned(
            left: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / (7 + rowCount),
            bottom: 48.0,
            child: Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 8.0, right: 8.0),
                  child: CircleAvatar(
                    backgroundColor: Color(0xff8951d9),
                    radius: 13,
                  ),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 8.0, right: 8.0),
                  child: CircleAvatar(
                    backgroundColor: Color(0xff3e51b5),
                    radius: 13,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            )),
        isNew
            ? Positioned(
                right: 4,
                top: 4,
                child: Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                      top: 8.0, right: 18.0, left: 18.0, bottom: 8.0),
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                        topRight: Radius.circular(5.0),
                        bottomLeft: Radius.circular(5.0),
                      )),
                  child: Text(
                    'NEW',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      fontSize: 14,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              )
            : Container(),
        isNew
            ? Positioned(
                right: 0,
                child: Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                      top: 8.0, right: 18.0, left: 18.0, bottom: 8.0),
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.red,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                        topRight: Radius.circular(5.0),
                        bottomLeft: Radius.circular(5.0),
                      )),
                  child: Text(
                    'NEW',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      fontSize: 14,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              )
            : Container(),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Hope this helps. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You can add the big image and two circular avatars in one Stack widget and then add bottom margin or padding or the big image and use Positioned widget for to two circular avatars wrapped inside a Row widget to get them placed at bottom of the big image.

Example:

```
Stack(
   children: <Widget>[
      Container(
         margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 40),
         child: BigImage(),
      ),
      Positioned(
         bottom: 20,
         child: Row(
            children: <Widget>[
               CircularAvatar(),
               CircularAvatar(),
            ],
         ),
      ),
   ],
)
```

This is a rough idea, You can try this and check if it is working or not.

Comment: This is exactly what I have done. I have updated my question. Please check.